# Angular elements - Element.createShadowRoot deprecation

Tags: javascript, angular, deprecation-warning, angular-elements

I'm testing Anuglar Elements to create some web components and is working great. Anyways I'm getting this warning in console:

> [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be
>   removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow
>   instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960
>   for more details.

Related file is platform-browser.js:1182.
Is something I should be aware of? How can i fix it? Should I search an alternative way to create my web components?

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN Web docs this feature is going to be removed completely. In any case it's not supported by most of the web browsers:

> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
> track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
> work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
> implementations and the behavior may change in the future.
>
> **Deprecated**
>
> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers
> might still support it, it may have already been removed from the
> relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may
> only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update
> existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom
> of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may
> cease to work at any time.

If you're using Angular i'd suggest using [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you will have to use

> Element.attachShadow instead.

**Example:**

```
class SomeElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
        console.log(this.shadowRoot);
    }
}

customElements.define('some-element', SomeElement);
```

The *mode* defines if you can access the shadow root through JavaScript.
For `{mode: 'closed'}` the code in the `connectedCallback` won't work since `this.shaodwRoot` returns `null`.